# How to make a table name changeable by the user in sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to make a program can create a table with a specific name in database every time I open it, but I can't do that because I will have two tables with the same name.... can I make the program ask the user to put different table name every time the code runs ?

```
Connection con = myConnection.getconnection();
PreparedStatement ps;
try {
    ps = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE TEST (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , dafat INT(255), sinif varchar (255), price INT (255) , type varchar (255), total INT (255), PRIMARY KEY (id))");
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("out");
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use one table, but have one of the keys be the user's id. The code would only allow the user to select, update, insert, and delete only rows with this specific user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can add a suffix to the table name when you build SQL query, but you'll need to validate user input to avoid SQL injections.

```java
    String tableSuffix = "_USER1";
    Connection con = myConnection.getconnection();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE TEST"+ userSuffix+" (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , dafat INT(255), sinif varchar (255), price INT (255) , type varchar (255), total INT (255), PRIMARY KEY (id))");
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error creating table TEST_" + userSuffix);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you intent to create `TEST` table every time while running your program ?. In that case try `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST` before creating new table.

Comment: No...  I want it to keep the table if it is exist and make another one with another name.... thats why I said how can I make the table name changeable by the user

Comment: @abdullahaffoura Please clarify via edits, not comments. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: Please do not answer unclear posts--if they are unclear then there is no question to answer. Guessing leads to messes. Comment to ask for clarifying edits. If you don't have the reputation to comment then wait until you do. [answer] [help] [ask]